# execute two methods at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on my first multithreaded app in many years.  The problem im having is i need to execute two methods at the same time.  here's my engine class:

```
public class ThreadPoolEngine {

    // create BlockingQueue to put fund transfer objects
    private BlockingQueue<GlobalSearchRequest> searchQueue;

    public ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    private HashMap<String, GlobalSearchProcessorCallable> callableMap;

    private ArrayList<Future<Integer>> futurList;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ThreadPoolEngine.class);

    private Integer gthreadCount;
    private Integer gjobPerThread;

    public ThreadPoolEngine(Integer threadCount, Integer jobPerThread) {
        gthreadCount = threadCount;
        gjobPerThread = jobPerThread;
        // create a thread pool with the entered no of threads
        executor = new HammerThreadPoolExecutor(threadCount, threadCount, 0L,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

        searchQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<GlobalSearchRequest>(jobPerThread);

        callableMap = new HashMap<String, GlobalSearchProcessorCallable>();

        // create list to store reference to Future objects
        futurList = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();
    }

    public void createAndSubmitTasks() {
        // create Callables
        for (int i = 0; i < gthreadCount; i++) {

            GlobalSearchProcessorCallable callable1 = new GlobalSearchProcessorCallable(
                    "SearchProcessor_" + i, searchQueue);
            callableMap.put(callable1.getThreadName(), callable1);

            // submit callable tasks
            Future<Integer> future;
            future = executor.submit(callable1);
            futurList.add(future);
        }
    }

    public void populateSearchQueue() throws InterruptedException {
        // put orderVO objects in BlockingQueue
        KeywordFactory key = KeywordFactory.getInstance();

        for (int i = 0; i < gjobPerThread*gthreadCount; i++) {
            // this method will put SearchRequest object in the order queue
            try {
                searchQueue.put(new GlobalSearchRequest(key.getRandomPhrase(3)));
            } catch (KeywordNoDataFileException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void printProcessorStatus() throws InterruptedException {
        // print processor status until all orders are processed
        while (!searchQueue.isEmpty()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, GlobalSearchProcessorCallable> e : callableMap
                    .entrySet()) {
                logger.debug(e.getKey() + " processed order count: "
                        + e.getValue().getProcessedCount());
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public void shutDown(boolean forceShutdown) {
        if (!forceShutdown) {
            // shutdown() method will mark the thread pool shutdown to true
            executor.shutdown();
            logger.debug("Executor shutdown status " + executor.isShutdown());
            logger.debug("Executor terninated status "
                    + executor.isTerminated());

            // Mark threads to return threads gracefully.
            for (Map.Entry<String, GlobalSearchProcessorCallable> orderProcessor : callableMap
                    .entrySet()) {
                orderProcessor.getValue().setRunning(false);
            }
        } else {

            for (Future<Integer> f : futurList) {
                f.cancel(true);
            }

            // shutdown() method will mark the thread pool shutdown to true
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    public void printWorkersResult() {
        for (Future<Integer> f : futurList) {
            try {
                Integer result = f.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                logger.debug(f + " result. Processed orders " + result);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                logger.error(e.getCause().getMessage(), e);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ok, i have a main class that instantiates this one and calls two methods on this class, the populateSearchQueue and the createAndSubmitTasks to run my worker class and process the items in the search queue.

The problem
the populateSearchQueue method could take a VERY long time to build (im going to hammer the system with one billion queries at a time) and it could take a lot of memory.  Is there a way in java where my main class can call the populateSearchQueue and the createAndSubmitTasks at the same time so the worker threads can start working on the queue while its still being built by the populateSearchQueue method?

Comment: it's unclear how the various tasks relate to each other.

Comment: "same time", with threads, I think is not an easy task.

Comment: please include the `import` statements on top of your code -- so we can paste it and help you more easily

Comment: where is `GlobalSearchRequest`?

Comment: can you provide the simplest code which illustrates your problem. if you need all that code just run two methods you have gone for overkill 9000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved it.  I read my code again and realized that it takes a tiny amount of time to create the thread pool. So call `createAndSubmitTasks` that creates the thread pool and each assigned a worker class waiting to do something.  When that method is done, I now have my pool of 1000 threads sitting there doing nothing. Then the moment I call `populateSearchQueue`, those worker threads that were sitting idle for the few milliseconds it took to move to the next method, now start grabbing jobs out of the queue, and I get my desired result. The method that is putting stuff in the queue is processing at the same time the worker threads are grabbing jobs out of that queue and running them.

So I reverse the order I'm calling the methods. It's a thing of beauty.